# Compute dynamic pvalue in rshiny based on users variable selection

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dataframe with several variables. One of them is continous and the other one is categorical.

I want to obtain wilcoxon test between these two variables, which is basically a metric to compare the difference between two groups of samples.
This is really easy when you know which factors you want to compare.

In base r this is pretty easy with the script:

```
# Pairwise Wilcox Test allow us to obtain multiple tests at the same time
multiple_wilcox <- function(response, factor) {
  pairwise.wilcox.test(response, factor, p.adjust.method = "none")$p.value[, 1]
}

# By default, tests are found against the reference level
with(iris, multiple_wilcox(Sepal.Length, Species))
#>   versicolor    virginica 
#> 8.345827e-14 6.396699e-17

# ... which can be changed with `relevel()`
with(iris, multiple_wilcox(Sepal.Length, relevel(Species, "virginica")))
```

I would like to implement this in shiny, so I would get all the p-values for a variable selected by the user.

This reactive function should do the work, as it's just the same.

```
  dat <- reactive({
    with(data_input(), multiple_wilcox(input$num_var_2, relevel(input$num_var_1, input$selected_factors)))
    })
```

But I'm getting the error:

[image]

I don't find where this error is coming from, as the data should be the same.

Here is the RepEx.

```
# Shiny
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjqui)
library(shinyjs)

# Data
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(vcd)

# Plots
library(ggplot2)

not_sel <- "Not Selected"

ui <- navbarPage(
  tabPanel(
    "",
    fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        sidebarPanel(
          title = "Inputs",
          fileInput("csv_input", "Select CSV file to import", accept = c(".csv")),
          selectInput("num_var_1", "Variable X axis", choices = c(not_sel)),
          selectInput("num_var_2", "Variable Y axis", choices = c(not_sel)),
          uiOutput("binning"),
          br(),
          actionButton("run_button", "Run Analysis", icon = icon("play"))
        ),
        
        # Main panel
        mainPanel(
          tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel(
              "Plot",
              br(),
              verbatimTextOutput("test"),
              uiOutput("var_stats"),
              br(),
              verbatimTextOutput("stats")),
           )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  
  # Load data and update inputs
  data_input <- reactive({
    #req(input$csv_input)
    #inFile <- input$csv_input
    #read.csv(inFile$datapath, 1)
    iris
  })
  
  observeEvent(data_input(),{
    choices <- c(not_sel, names(data_input()))
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_1", choices = choices)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_2", choices = choices)
  })
  
  num_var_1 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_1)
  num_var_2 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_2)
  
  output$var_stats <- renderUI({
    req(input$num_var_1, data_input())
    if (input$num_var_1 != not_sel) {
      a <- unique(data_input()[[input$num_var_1]])
      pickerInput(inputId = 'selected_factors',
                  label = 'Select factors',
                  choices = c(a), selected=a[3], multiple = F,
                  options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE))
    }
    
  })
  
  
  multiple_wilcox <- function(response, factor) {
    pairwise.wilcox.test(response, factor, p.adjust.method = "none")$p.value[, 1]
  }

  dat <- reactive({
    with(data_input(), multiple_wilcox(input$num_var_2, relevel(input$num_var_1, input$selected_factors)))
    })
  
  output$test <- renderPrint({
    dat()
  })
  
}

# Connection for the shinyApp
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

As `relevel()` is not working in shiny, you may need to change the factor manually as shown below.

```
not_sel <- "Not Selected"

ui <- navbarPage(
  tabPanel(
    "",
    fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        sidebarPanel(
          title = "Inputs",
          fileInput("csv_input", "Select CSV file to import", accept = c(".csv")),
          selectInput("num_var_1", "Variable X axis", choices = c(not_sel)),
          selectInput("num_var_2", "Variable Y axis", choices = c(not_sel)),
          uiOutput("binning"),
          br(),
          actionButton("run_button", "Run Analysis", icon = icon("play"))
        ),
        
        # Main panel
        mainPanel(
          tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel(
              "Plot",
              br(),
              verbatimTextOutput("test"),
              uiOutput("var_stats"),
              br(),
              verbatimTextOutput("stats")),
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  
  # Load data and update inputs
  data_input <- reactive({
    #req(input$csv_input)
    #inFile <- input$csv_input
    #read.csv(inFile$datapath, 1)
    iris
  })
  
  observeEvent(data_input(),{
    choices <- c(not_sel, names(data_input()))
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_1", choices = choices)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_2", choices = choices)
  })
  
  num_var_1 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_1)
  num_var_2 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_2)
  
  output$var_stats <- renderUI({
    req(input$num_var_1, data_input())
    if (input$num_var_1 != "Not Selected") {
      a <- as.list(as.character(unique(data_input()[[input$num_var_1]])))
      
      pickerInput(inputId = 'selected_factors',
                  label = 'Select factors',
                  choices = list(Factor=a), selected=a[[3]], multiple = F,
                  options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE))
    }
    
  })
  
  
  multiple_wilcox <- function(response, factor) {
    pairwise.wilcox.test(response, factor, p.adjust.method = "none")$p.value[, 1]
  }
  
  dat <- eventReactive(input$run_button, {
    req(data_input(),input$num_var_1,input$num_var_2,input$selected_factors)
    
    #with(data_input(), multiple_wilcox(input$num_var_2, relevel(input$num_var_1, input$selected_factors)))
    
    df <- data_input()
    fac <- unique(data_input()[[input$num_var_1]][data_input()[[input$num_var_1]] != input$selected_factors])
    df$new <- data_input()[[input$num_var_1]]
    newlevels <- c(input$selected_factors,as.character(fac))
    df$new <- factor(df$new, levels=newlevels)
    
    with(df, multiple_wilcox(df[[input$num_var_2]], new))
    
  })
  
  output$test <- renderPrint({
    dat()
  })
  
}

# Connection for the shinyApp
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```